# Where does the "Character Map" program executable reside in XP?

Tags: windows-xp, shortcuts

Where does the "Character Map" program  executable reside in Windows XP?

I want to point a short cut to it. I did so via right clicking on the menu icon, but when I try to use it, I get the message that it cannot be found.

Comment: If you go to Start->Run, type `charmap`, and press enter - does the app come up?

Comment: Yes. I have access to it but I wish to reduce the movements needed to access it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows XP it's located in:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32\charmap.exe
```

But, there should already be a shortcut in the Start Menu:

```
Start > All Programs > Accessories > System Tools > Character Map
```

Comment: Thanks. I know how to find it but I want to make it much easier to get to, so I want to put a shortcut on the task bar.

Comment: OK - I didn't completely understand your question. So, your problem is that the shortcut you create doesn't work?

Comment: Thanks. You seem to have solved my problem. +1 plus accept. Yes the previous shortcut did not work.
Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

You could also find where the executable reside when you open the application, then go to Task Manager, in Application tab right-click on application you want to find and select Go to process. A process of the application will be highlighted, right click on it and select Open File location.

This is possible in Windows 7, I don't know if Task managers of previous versions of Windows can do this though.

Comment: No, previous versions can't do this, but winternals/sysinternals Process Explorer can.